# Saving files in a S3 subfolder

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

If I'm not mistaken, there are no real folders in S3. But there seems to be a possibility to save files with path's so it looks like a folder (when navigated through the AWS console, the folders are even visible).

Having a FileField in Django, how would I append a folder name to it?

E.g. the below works but is being put in the root bucket, which becomes cluttered very quickly. I'd love to put all those files in a 'subfolder'

```
class presentation(models.Model):
    """ Holds the presentation themselves"""
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        help_text='PPT or other presentation accessible only to members',
        storage=protected_storage,
    )

protected_storage = storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage(
    acl='private',
    querystring_auth=True,
    querystring_expire=120,  # 2 minutes, try to ensure people won't/can't share
)
```

Comment: If by `subfolder`, you mean `bucket`, then mention the `bucket` argument to `S3Boto3Storage` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the upload_to parameter and have it point to a function.

```
def my_upload_func(instance, filename):
    return f"test/awesome/{filename}"

file = models.FileField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        help_text='PPT or other presentation accessible only to members',
        storage=protected_storage,
        upload_to=my_upload_func
)
```

Comment: worked beautifully, thanks a lot! What is the instance for, though, if it's not used in the upload func?

Comment: instance is if you wanted to derive some type of attribute from the presentation. let's say you wanted to put it in the bucket of author's name with f"{instance.author.name}/{filename}"